# Getting type mismatch when using sealed class with rxjava in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have following code

```
sealed class AddressUiState
object AddressLoading : AddressUiState()
class AddressLoadedState(val addressResponse: AddressBookResponse) : AddressUiState()
class AddressErrorState(val error: Throwable) : AddressUiState()
```

and I have ViewModel like below

```
class AddressViewModel constructor(private val service: SingleProfileService) : ViewModel() {

    fun getDisplayableAddressState(id: String): Observable<out AddressUiState> {
        return service.getAddresses(id)
                .map { AddressLoadedState(it) }
                .startWith(AddressLoading)
                .onErrorReturn { AddressErrorState(it) }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

    }
}
```

I'm seeing the compilation error and onErrorReturn with error
**Type mismatch. Required: AddressLoadedState! found: AddressErrorState**
What is wrong with above code?

Comment: Note that `startWith { }`  won't work, use `startWith()` with regular parenthesis.

Comment: You should add the rxjava tag.

Answer (score 18):

in your code

```
.map { AddressLoadedState(it) }
```

gives a

```
Observable<AddressLoadedState>
```

The onError function expects a Function that takes an exception and returns something that extends T.

```
Observable<T> onErrorReturn(Func1<? super Throwable, ? extends T> resumeFunction)
```

In this case, T is AddressLoadedState.  AddressErrorState does not extend this, so the compiler will complain.

You could split the statements into more than one line to help the compiler though, to show it T is actually a AddressUiState.  Or you can also tell the compiler on the map function itself like this:

```
    return service.getAddresses(id)
            .map<AddressUiState> { AddressLoadedState(it) }
            .startWith(AddressLoading)
            .onErrorReturn { AddressErrorState }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```